# Creating a silverlight Business Application Project hosted in IIS

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm, iis-7.5, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I want to create a Silverlight Business Application that uses my machine's Local Web Server, and that accesses a SQL SERVER Express database under the MVVM approach, using EF, Domain Serices and RIA Services.

I'm a Windows 7 user with VS2010 or 2012.

**Which of the following is a better practice?**:

**First Approach**) Create a Web Site that uses http location (IIS 7.5), then add a Silverlight Business Application project to it. All DomainServices, Views and ViewModels will be located in BusinessApplication and BusinessApplication.Web projects. The LocalHost project will only serve as the way to open the project to the world:

[image http://s8.postimage.org/fveorpir9/Sin_T_tulo.jpg](http://s8.postimage.org/fveorpir9/Sin_T_tulo.jpg)

**Second Approach**) Create a Silverlight Business Application, check the BusinessApplication.Web property Web->Use local IIS Web Server and proceed creating the models, domainservices and so on...

[image: image2]

**Third Approach**) Create a WebSite located on localhost, and add a Silverlight Project hosted in the web site. This approach doesn't use the Business Application Template. Not interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the 2. Approach to setup your silverlight project. For starting with development of silverlight web applications. The Business Application Template will setup many settings and options for you, so that you can directly implement your business logic.

I´m as a experienced silverlight developer use the 3. Approach, cause i don´t like to use those templates as they provide to many for my needs.

Comment: But I guess you don't use Authentication, or those kind of things that make the Business Application Template atractive...

Comment: I use AuthenticationService, RoleProvider, DomainService and the other stuff, but i don´t rely on those templates.

Comment: So you developed your own templates. I guess you have had problems with them and decided to develop the all. Ok then, that's a lot of work to do that I have ahead. I guess that while I'm studying I'm better off using the SBA.